# ¿Como hago con regex para permitir solamente llaves en una linea de texto y que el texto sea solamente uno?

Tags: c#, regex

Lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente:

Me llegaran dos tipos de lineas en mi string.

linea 1: `"}else{"` - esta es la quiero que matche que tenga la palabra reservada else y que permita uno o dos llaves ya sea adelante o atrás

Linea 2: `"}else if(cond){"` - esta no quiero que matchee

con el código actual las dos matchean.

Código regex:

```
\b(else)\b
```

Debería matchear así

```
caso 1 : }else{
caso 2 : else{
caso 3 : else 
caso 4 :              else
```

Comment: y que otro caso debería machear ? xq si es solo ese caso, pones }else{

Comment: @FederHico ya  modifique el post para que veas los posibles casos, saludos

Comment: @abulafia si funciono, si la pones como respuesta la pongo como buena, saludos

Comment: }?\b(else)\b[{|}]? se acerca bastante pero no :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una expresión regular que funciona para tu caso es

```
"^ *}? *else *{? *$"
```

Eso permite cualquier número de espacios desde el inicio de la línea (`^`), seguido de una llave opcional y de cualquier otro número de espacios, la palabra `else`, de nuevo espacios y otra llave opcional, más espacios, y el final de línea (`$`).

Demo --> https://regex101.com/r/DKmiU0/1